# Why this strange thing happening in my list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list and I want to traverse reverse in my list and change each element with the previous element until first element:

```
lst = [[1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,4]]
for i in range(len(lst) - 1, 0, -1):
    lst[i] = lst[i-1]

lst[0][0] += 1
```

After that, this is what result I expect:

```
>>> lst
[[2, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
```

But the result is this:

```
>>> lst
[[2, 2], [2, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
```

I heard something about referencing between 2 lists when you assign them into each other, but the question is why this result not going to happen for other elements, for example:

```
lst = [[1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,4]]
for i in range(len(lst) - 1, 0, -1):
    lst[i] = lst[i-1]

lst[2][0] += 1
```

This is result:

```
>>> lst
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 4]]
```

What I expect:

```
>>> lst
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4]]
```

Why there isn't any referencing between `lst[2]` and `lst[3]`?

Comment: You say you get `[[1, 2], [2, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]` from the second snippet, but [that's not what I see](https://ideone.com/ya6rYZ).

Comment: You put the list from `lst[0]` in `lst[1]` and you didn't reassign `lst[0]` to something else.

Comment: @khelwood Sorry, Question was edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's give your sublists individual names, so your list is initially

```
lst = [a, b, c, d]
```

Now you perform this loop:

```
for i in range(len(lst) - 1, 0, -1):
    lst[i] = lst[i-1]
```

At each step this is what you get:

```
# lst[3] = lst[2]
[a, b, c, c]
# lst[2] = lst[1]
[a, b, b, c]
# lst[1] = lst[0]
[a, a, b, c]
```

Now you end up with `lst[0]` and `lst[1]` being the same object, so when you make a change inside `lst[0]` you see the same change in `lst[1]`

Comment: But, If I make change to lst[2] why lst[3] won't change?

Comment: Because `lst[2]` and `lst[3]` are different objects (`b` and `c` in my answer).

Comment: @khlewood Why? I've assigned lst[2] and lst[3] before. Aren't they same object too?

Comment: No, because you subsequently set `lst[2]` to a *different* object.